# Java what is the type of (long a - double b)

Tags: java

So as asked in the title:
what happens internally when doing substracting a double value from a long value? Is the result from type double or long and is this behavior even specified in the Java specification or is this behavior jvm specific?

So I know that I can test myself what my jvm does:

```
    public class Test {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        double b = 1000;
        long a = 1000;
        Object c = a - b;
        Class cls = c.getClass();  
        System.out.println("The type of the object is: " + cls.getName());
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
    The type of the object is: java.lang.Double
```

But is this specified somewhere? Or is it specific to the jvm I used?

Comment: Question: What else could be the result?

Comment: Well the result could be a long ...

Comment: I would guess, since double is more specific (when considering floating point) than long, that long will be converted to double before the operation, and therefor, the result is double, edit: by converting double to long, you would lose all the floating point values, this conversion would be pointless

Comment: Yes, I know that. But my question wasn't what a good choice for the compiler would be, but on which choice of the compiler I can rely on across multiple jvms :-D

Comment: @noamik the resualt cannot be long since long does not support floating point

Comment: @MarcoForberg This isn't really within the scope of my question. I know why I would want it to be a double. But while not being a good choice, the result could very well be a long. You would lose precision on the result, that's all. The result could even be a bool, it all depends on what you want to achieve and on the function you implemented to allow such casts ...

Comment: neither boolean nor long make sense in this case. so why should the jvm implement it that way?

Comment: My question wasn't if it made sense. I've been building compilers myself in the past, so I can judge by myself if a behavior makes sense or not. My question was if there was some behavior specified and since I lacked a good pointer to find the answer to it, I asked here. The question has been answered to it's fullest extend. I don't see the point in this discussion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the applicable part of the spec:

**4.2.4. Floating-Point Operations**

> If at least one of the operands to a numerical operator is of type
>   double, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit floating-point
>   arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of
>   type double. If the other operand is not a double, it is first widened
>   (§5.1.5) to type double by numeric promotion (§5.6).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question. I'll accept your answer as soon as it's allowed ...

Comment: @noamik Glad I can help. You seem alot like me, don't tell me what it does, tell my why it does it.

Answer (score 4):

1. Since `a` is a long and `b` is a `double` `a - b` produces a `double` ([Floating-Point Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4)).

   > If at least one of the operands to a numerical operator is of type double, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type double. If the other operand is not a double, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type double by numeric promotion (§5.6).
2. The `double` result is then autoboxed to type `Double` ([Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)).

Comment: Well, I know that my jvm acted like that. But the question is more: why did it do so? And please don't respond with technical reasoning, because I can do that myself as well. What I want is either a pointer to the spec specifying how to cast in such situations or a (substantiated) claim that the decision how to act is left to the jvm implementation.

Comment: @noamik Added links to the Java® Language Specification.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things going on here. The a - b operation produces a double - this is widening of primitives to accomodate for loss of information.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1

You are then assigning the result to an Object reference (Object c = a - b;) which produces an autoboxing of primitive double to Double object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointers. I accepted Kevin's answer since he had it first.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that given there is a double in the formula, the result is bound to be a double (or at least a floating point number) if there is no cast.

It's the same as (10 / 3) will be an int and (10.0 / 3) will not.

Answer (score 0):

Yep in fact the output type will always be the type of the left variable of your opperation. Your compiler will try to convert or cast your right parameter. If it is possible, it will compile, if not you will have a compilation error.

Comment: The left variable is a long in this case, so this doesn't seem the case.